# distinct name with each their max value sorted by their own max value with a condition in sql

Tags: sql

I currently have the following table:

```
    Name    |  key   |  State
    User 1  |  12    |  15
    User 2  |  12    |  100
    User 3  |  144   |  35
    User 1  |  66    |  21
    User 1  |  72    |  25
    User 3  |  12    |  22
    User 2  |  12    |  50
```

i want to find user then get its maximum state number and sort the maximum state from highest value where it has a column key=12.

the rexpected result is this.

```
    Name    |  key   |  State
    User 2  |  12    |  100
    User 3  |  12    |  22
    User 1  |  12    |  15
```

i cant solve the problem myself that is why i need help, sorry for that though

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: do you want me to show my the real table im using not the one in the example ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
SELECT
    Name
    ,Key
    ,MAX(State) AS State
FROM your_table
WHERE Key = 12
GROUP BY Name, Key
ORDER BY State DESC
```

Comment: what if the state is datetime with a datetime values??

Comment: would work the same ... will return `MAX` of datetime

Comment: ive tried your code and it works but changing to date type to datetime  with date time values, it didnt sort out on desc neither asc

Comment: thanks for the help anyway it totally helps me a lot

Comment: I guess something is wrong in your data ... check here an example with datetime: [Example](http://rextester.com/HTWRF95068)

Comment: does it have to do with the name column changing into a number with int data type and values??
thats why it didn't sort  out correctly

Comment: lol i found the answer, i made a mistake on the part where "max(state) as state",
i mistakely  changed it to "max(state) as states"

thank you miss. valerica,
im just a trying hard programmer here

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

```
SELECT Name, key, MAX(state) AS state
FROM <tablename>
WHERE key = 12
GROUP BY Name, key
ORDER BY state Desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, key, MAX(State) as State
FROM <tabe>
WHERE 
 key = 12
GROUP BY Name, key
ORDER BY State DESC
```

Comment: what if the state is datetime with a datetime values??

Comment: @Calaydo Minds return max datetime

Comment: i tried new problem, its like the date type on state column is datetime and with new datetime values,  then i use max(state) with date type of datetime but it didn't work

Comment: type column datetime or varchar?